# how to create a model for following requirements

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, wagtail

I have profile model, it have multiple fields like passing, receiving, shooting. Then each fields have 4 section like(Right, Left, Top, Bottom). How to store the 4 different value for the every single field.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement you could use `CharField` with the different values as choices.

Ex:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    MY_CHOICES = (
        ('R', 'Right'),
        ('L', 'Left'),
        ('T', 'Top'),
        ('B', 'Bottom')
    )
    passing = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=MY_CHOICES, default='R', blank=True)
    receiving = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=MY_CHOICES, default='R', blank=True)
    shooting = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=MY_CHOICES, default='R', blank=True)
```

Comment: it's like a form, that form filled by user

Comment: its like table, for passing they filled 4 values for L, R, T, B, then again next field for receiving they filled 4 values for L, R, T, B.

Comment: You have provided very little information. You want to store 4 different value for the every single field, that is not possible. One field can have only one value. You need to define 4 fields for four values that is, in total 12 fields for your requirement.

Comment: I have 10 fields,  so I want to create 40 fields in my model?

Comment: You have mentioned that ' each fields have 4 section like(Right, Left, Top, Bottom). store the 4 different value for the every single field'. But you can't have values of 4 sections into one field. That's against database rule. Because as per your requirement, each section will be treated as an individual field.

Comment: So I don't have any choice right? due to this problem i planned to create 40 fields. It's the worst idea i know, but currently i don't have any idea about this

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're describing is actually several related models. Without the full details of what this data is representing, I have to guess at the most suitable names for those models - but let's say that 'passing', 'receiving' etc are skills, and you're measuring people's skill levels in those categories. The list of skills would then belong in a 'Skill' model - i.e. if you have 10 different skills, then this would be a table with 10 entries, one for each skill. Then, whenever you store a person's results, you would store that as a set of linked records: one entry in the Person model, along with as many PersonSkillLevel records as you need to cover all of the skills. Your models would look like this:

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class PersonSkillLevel(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    right = models.IntegerField()
    left = models.IntegerField()
    top = models.IntegerField()
    bottom = models.IntegerField()
```

And the data stored in these would be something like:

Skill:

```
id | name
---------------
 1 | Passing
 2 | Receiving
 3 | Shooting
```

Person:

```
id | first_name | last_name
---------------------------
 1 | Bobson     | Dugnutt
 2 | Todd       | Bonzalez
```

PersonSkillLevel:

```
id | person | skill | right | left | top | bottom
 1 |      1 |     1 |    12 |   23 |  24 |     31  <- Bobson Dugnutt's scores for Passing
 2 |      1 |     2 |    13 |   15 |  21 |     17  <- Bobson Dugnutt's scores for Receiving
 3 |      2 |     1 |    25 |   14 |  20 |     12  <- Todd Bonzalez's scores for Passing
 4 |      2 |     2 |    16 |   22 |  15 |     24  <- Todd Bonzalez's scores for Receiving
```